# What is wrong with my joining derived table query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Im pretty new to SQL and just started learning about derived tables.
the thing is created two tables, one without null and one with null
but i cant seem to understand why the join wont work.
i get the errors "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OUTER'." **and** "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'." but i still don't understand...

here is my code:

```
SELECT customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_status) AS rownum,
customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
FROM Sales.orders) AS T 
WHERE shipped_date IS NOT NULL

OUTER JOIN

SELECT customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_status) AS rownum,
customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
FROM Sales.orders) AS T2
WHERE shipped_date IS  NULL

ON T.customer_id = T2.customerid;
```

Comment: JOIN comes before WHERE.

Comment: @michox2 . . . Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  You are calculating `rownum` but don't seem to be using it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

try like below

```
    select a.*,b.*  from (SELECT customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
    FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_status) AS rownum,
    customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
    FROM Sales.orders) AS T 
    WHERE shipped_date IS NOT NULL
   ) a    
    left JOIN

    (SELECT customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
    FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_status) AS rownum,
    customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
    FROM Sales.orders) AS T2
    WHERE shipped_date IS  NULL
   ) b    
    ON a.customer_id = b.customerid;
```

BTW you can do it by using one query

```
SELECT customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
        FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_status) AS rownum,
        customer_id, order_id, order_status, shipped_date
        FROM Sales.orders) AS T2
        WHERE shipped_date IS  NULL or shipped_date is not null
```

Comment: thank you :) it works now can you explain to me what the a.*/b.* does please?

Comment: @michox2 a and b is alias name of your 1st and 2nd query